# Determine median using php

Tags: php, radio-button, median

I have an HTML page that has radio buttons that you can choose from. One is Age Range, and the other one is Salary Range. These are handled by a php file, what i want to do is be able to print

- The user’s age range
- The user’s salary range
- The median salary for the user’s age range
- A statement about how the user compares to the median for his/her age

  So far i am only printing the user's age range, and salary range. I cannot figure out how to print  the other ones.

  ## Income

  ```
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td>
              Age Range</td>
          <td colspan="2">
              Salary Range</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio1"  checked="checked" name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" />15 to 
              24 Years</td>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio7" checked="checked" name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$15,000 
              to $24,999</td>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio13"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$75,000 
              to $84,999</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio2"  name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" />25 to 
              34 Years</td>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio8"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$25,000 
              to $34,999</td>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio14"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$85,000 
              to $94,999</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio3"  name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" />35 to 
              44 Years</td>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio9"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$35,000 
              to $44,999</td>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio15"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$95,000 
              to $104,999</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio4" name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" />45 to 
              54 Years</td>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio10"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$45,000 
              to $54,999</td>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio16"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$105,000 
              to $114,999</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio5"  name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" />55 to 
              64 Years</td>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio11" name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$55,000 
              to $64,999</td>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio17"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$115,000 
              to $124,999</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio6"  name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" />65 
              Years and Older</td>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio12"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$65,000 
              to $74,999</td>
          <td>
              <input id="Radio18"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$125,000 
              and up</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="See Where You Stand">
  ```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Income</title>
<style>

body { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
body { font-size: 85%; }


</style>



</head>
<body style="background-color:lightgray; ">

<form action="AgeGroupSalaryRange.php" method="post" name="agegroup">

<h1>Income</h1>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Age Range</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                Salary Range</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio1"  checked="checked" name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" />15 to 
                24 Years</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio7" checked="checked" name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$15,000 
                to $24,999</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio13"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$75,000 
                to $84,999</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio2"  name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" />25 to 
                34 Years</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio8"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$25,000 
                to $34,999</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio14"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$85,000 
                to $94,999</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio3"  name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" />35 to 
                44 Years</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio9"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$35,000 
                to $44,999</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio15"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$95,000 
                to $104,999</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio4" name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" />45 to 
                54 Years</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio10"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$45,000 
                to $54,999</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio16"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$105,000 
                to $114,999</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio5"  name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" />55 to 
                64 Years</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio11" name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$55,000 
                to $64,999</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio17"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$115,000 
                to $124,999</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio6"  name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" />65 
                Years and Older</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio12"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$65,000 
                to $74,999</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Radio18"  name="R7" type="radio" value="V1" />$125,000 
                and up</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="See Where You Stand">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the php code

```
<?php
$agerange = $_POST['R1'];
$incomerange = $_POST['R7'];
/*$mediansalary = */




?>

<?php 


AgeBrackets: ("15 to 24 Years", "25 to 34 Years", "35 to 44 Years", "45 to     54 Years", "55 to 64 Years", "65 Years and Older");




MedianIncome: (34311, 52702, 64973, 67141, 57538, 35611);




IncomeRangesStart: (15000, 25000, 35000, 45000, 55000, 65000, 75000, 85000, 95000, 105000, 115000, 125000);




?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I apologize, i forgot to mention that 34,311 is the median salary for the 15-to-24-Years age range, etc. And also, i have to compare the user’s selected Income Range to the median for his/her age. using the three possibilities that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function will return the median of an array of values.

```
<?php
function getMedian($arr) {
    sort($arr);
    $count = count($arr);
    $middleval = floor(($count-1)/2);
    if ($count % 2) {
        $median = $arr[$middleval];
    } else {
        $low = $arr[$middleval];
        $high = $arr[$middleval+1];
        $median = (($low+$high)/2);
    }
    return $median;
}
```

I'm struggling to understand your form/code and to see what this array might be, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: I apologize, i forgot to mention that 34,311 is the median salary for the 15-to-24-Years age range, etc. And also, i have to compare the user’s selected Income Range to the median for his/her age. using the three possibilities that I mentioned above.

Comment: You will need to get a list (array) of all salaries for that age range and use the function above to find the median of that list. For example; in MySQL: `SELECT incomeRange FROM table WHERE ageRange = "$_POST['R1']";` (very simplified). Without saying how you're storing data and processing the submitted data, that's as much help as you can get.

Comment: Thank you, I will elaborate on what you mentioned and gave me, I appreciate it.